# Default User Agent (WebClient Header)

Tags: c#, webclient

Long explanation made short, I NEED to supply a proper user agent when posting data to my server; Why? I don't know entirely.

In any case, I've read that making a web request prior and grabbing the header from it would suffice, but I'd like to know if there's a more cleaner/sufficient method.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed just grab one from your favourite browser, or pick one from [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

The user agent string is just that - a string containing various info about the browser. So it's just a matter of passing it along with you request. If your program will live for a while, I'd try to pick one that's as generic as possible.